# Does there exists something like Macros in Golang for debugging

Tags: go

Does there exist also something like macros of C/C++ in golang so that in debug phase, developers are allowed to print some additional debug information? And in the official release, just set these macros to false so that they will not be compiled and no extra information will be printed. Here is a snippet to illustrate what I mean.

```
func demo() {
    // ...
    // the following line will not be compiled in release only in debug phase
    
    printMyDebugInfo(variable)
    
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No, there are not.

Comment: Does there exist another methods to fulfill the same requirement?

Comment: Swap out the `printMyDebugInfo` implementation based on build tags? Make `printMyDebugInfo` only print when given the correct config or env variable? Conditional logging is pretty standard for most any significant program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest is probably to define a debug print function in two versions.

One for debug mode:

```
//go:build debug

package whatever

func debugPrint(in string) {
    print(in)
}
```

One for production:

```
//go:build !debug

package whatever

func debugPrint(in string) {}
```

Then use `go build -tags debug` when you want to use the debug version.